# Symfony 5 - Installing API on VPS

Tags: symfony

i've installed a Symfony on my local LAMP. It works.
Then i've used the "composer require api" it works (with php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public).

I've done the same thing on my VPS (same conf). Symfony OK. But API NOK without php -S domain.name:8000 -t public. But with php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public it is working.
Here my VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/A2SAPI/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/A2SAPI/public>
        AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

        # Copy .htaccess contents here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    # ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/A2SAPI/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/A2SAPI/public>
        AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

        # Copy .htaccess contents here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know how to setup correctly the VirtualHost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why did you use PHP's internal webserver, combined with an Apache webserver?

Comment: In VPS, do you have composer installed?

Comment: @YahyaE why should that be relevant? You don't need to install Composer on a production system to use Symfony

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP docs:

> Warning
> This web server is designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

You should really look in to having Apache handle the PHP instead of using the PHP dev internal server. If you are looking for an easier alternative to Apache I strongly recommend Caddy server (https://caddyserver.com/)

Otherwise make sure Composer is either installed or that all dependencies of the api bundle have been copied to your server.